Left arrow and right arrow keys not working in google chrome search bar
Whenever I right anything in my google chrome search bar and press arrow keys, either the left or the right, the text-cursor must move one character left or right. But such thing does not happen in my case. What actually occurs is that, the focus is brought out of the text area and shifted to other elements. Why is so?
It only happens in Chrome. Moreover, it occurs in every profile of Google Chrome, but not on other browsers. I have tried removing all the browser extensions, but it did not seem to work. What is the fix?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try to update your chrome.
This happened to me as well, and this is pretty annoying.
but seems to have fixed today.
I've updated to Version 130.0.6723.59 (Official Build) (arm64).

I confirm this is an issue with 129.0.6668.103, but it's fixed in the build you mentioned.

Unfortunately the solution @McCandless posted, is not working in 130.0.6723.70 (Offizieller Build) (arm64). Version from 29. October 2024, updated today.
Using the cursor keys in the search bar is not possible.
They select the elements left and right of the search bar, like the OP described.
Super annoying.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Looks like this is caused by the "Swipe between pages" option in Settings > Accessibility. This seems to have been turned on by default in an update. I turned it off, and the cursor started behaving correctly in the address bar. No idea why Google decided to enable that!

For anyone else finding this soo much annoying Just try just 2 steps:
type chrome://restart in  address bar to restart your chrome.
OR
Update your chrome Browser to latest stable version.
This should fix this issue.
As everyone else is mentioning. This issue is occuring due to accessibility. For someone who need screen reader or visual assistance this option might be great.

I understood your situation, the extensions sometimes may cause that kind of problem so the solution is unfortunately removing them from chrome. Just go one by one and try to figure out which one is the problem and then you can keep the rest of your extension within your browser. Hope this helps!

This is not very helpful. Extensions cannot modify the way the Chrome URL field or its general keyboard shortcuts behave, so it's incorrect to assume they'd change text editing behavior.

The poster mentioned they removed all extensions and it didn't resolve the issue. I'm having the same problem as the poster and haven't adjusted my extensions in months. Moreover, there are people all over the internet who are upset about this change in behavior.
